# Using Twitter4j to get favorited count for a particular tweet

Tags: java, twitter4j

I am new to the twitter4j api, is there any way of getting no of favorite count for a particular tweet using twitter4j. I am using api version 3.0.3 for Twitter4j.

In documentation the method `getFavoriteCount()` is present but the same method gives compilation error in code. Should I use different version of jar file?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

     ConfigurationBuilder cb= new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cb.setDebugEnabled(true);
        cb.setOAuthConsumerKey("**************************");
        cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret("**************************");
        cb.setOAuthAccessToken("*******************************");
        cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("*****************************");
        Twitter  twitter = new TwitterFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();
         User user = null;
        try {
            user = twitter.verifyCredentials();
        } catch (TwitterException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        String[] test = new String[]{"teststr"};
        ResponseList<User> users;
        try {
            users = twitter.lookupUsers(test);

        for (User user1 : users) {
              if (user1.getStatus() != null)
              {
                  Paging paging = new Paging(1, 40);
                  ResponseList<Status> statusess =   twitter.getUserTimeline(user1.getName(),paging);

              for (Status status3 : statusess)
               {
                long retweetCount = status3.getRetweetCount();
                long favoriteCount = status3.getFavoriteCount();/** this line gives compilation error saying the method getFavoriteCount() is undefined for the type Status**/

               }
              }
        }
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

 }
```

Comment: yes you can call the method getFavouriteCount() on a status object. You should read the documentation try something and post the code you have tried when you get stuck.  It is much easier for people to help you this way and saves us googling the answer for you. http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/Status.html#getFavoriteCount()

Comment: @robthewolf i have read the documentation and i tried also same thing but code doesn't compile says no signature of getFavoriteCount() method for the particular object, thats why i got confused i downloaded the jar from the twitter4j site. I got this error "The method getFavoriteCount() is undefined for the type Status". do i need to use some other version of jar

Comment: @gusaindpk You should add the suspect piece of code, the compilation error and relevant details to your question so people can help. You are not going to get much of a response with the question as it is.

Comment: @Jonathan my bad added the code and explained the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems like the JavaDocs on the Twitter4J site linked next to the 3.0.3 release are not correct. The actual docs are [here](http://twitter4j.org/oldjavadocs/3.0.3/twitter4j/Status.html) - you can see that `getFavoriteCount()` isn't present in these.

It looks like `Status#getFavoriteCount()` was only [introduced in 3.0.4](http://jira.twitter4j.org/browse/TFJ-763). So yes, you need to upgrade from 3.0.3 in order to use this method.

Although be aware that version 3.0.4 looks like it is under active development presently.

Comment: thanks,is there any other way of getting the favorite count??

Comment: @gusaindpk No problem. I would try using the `3.0.4-SNAPSHOT` version myself.

Comment: Incidentally, I've submitted a bug about this to the project - hopefully they'll fix it soon.

Answer (score 0):

Although you have already found and marked an answer, let me provide an alternate to switching the Twitter4J version.

When using a method similar to what you are using, I had searched a lot and finally found the solution in an entirely unrelated post. Here is how you can get the Favorite count of tweets:

**NOTE:** *This is what I use in an Android app of mine.*

First, in your `ConfigurationBuilder cb` instance, add this one line:

```
cb.setJSONStoreEnabled(true);
```

This will return all results in a JSON format. Strangely, getting a JSON result it provides you that value.

Now, to fetch the *Tweets*:

```
try {
    Paging paging = new Paging(initPagingOffset, 200);
    statuses = twitter.getHomeTimeline(paging);

    String strTweets = DataObjectFactory.getRawJSON(statuses);
    JSONArray JATweets = new JSONArray(strTweets);

    for (int i = 0; i < JATweets.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject JOTweets = JATweets.getJSONObject(i);

        ..... // PARSE ANY OTHER DATA YOU MIGHT NEED FOR DISPLAYING THE TWEETS

        String FAV_COUNT = JOTweet.getString("favorite_count");

    }
} catch (TwitterException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```